# How to list files of a folder using contentsOfDirectoryAtURL

Tags: ios, webserver, nsurl, nsfilemanager, enumerator

I explain my problem: I have some files in my computer, and I want to read them from my iPhone thanks to the Wi-fi (Wi-fi to begin, and after with the 3G network).

- I opened the WebServer on my computer (maybe it isn't the better solution to answer at my problem, I don't know), so I succeed in reading files whose I have the exactly path like this:
  `NSURL *serverFile = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.9/AccountNumber.txt"];
  NSString *number = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:serverFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
  NSLog(@"%@",number);  // It works`
- To check if a file exists, I use NSURLSession like here:

  `NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:dossierDevice];
  request.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";
  NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration]];
  NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
       NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
       if (statusCode == 200 || statusCode == 403) {
       NSLog(@"EXIST");// success
       }
       else {
       NSLog(@"DON'T EXIST");// failure
       }
       }];
       [task resume];`
- But now my problem is to list the files of a folder. Before, when I made the tests from my computer to himself (with the simulator), I used `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` which worked perfectly. 
  But now, when I use something like `NSMutableArray *allAccounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:AccountFolder includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:nil]];` that return me an empty NSMutableArray.

How can I fixe this problem ? Thanks.

PS: I have the same problem to enumerate a list of files from a folder

Answer (score 0):

his kind of enumeration only works for NSURLs with file:/// and not http://. You could use a file server (e.g. webdav, afp, smb or similar) instead of a webserver.